# How to fix this error: Collection <__NSDictionaryM: 0x6000005ab3a0> was mutated while being enumerated?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, error-handling

I have a table view with multiple sections. It's allowed to select only one item in each section, and when a user clicks on any item, all selected items in next sections deselect.

Some times I get an error when the user clicks on an item. it's not always happening.

Here is my code

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary *selectionData;


-(void)handleSelectionForSection:(long)sectionIndex row:(long)rowIndex
{

    if ([self.selectionData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sectionIndex] ] != nil) {

        NSMutableArray *sectionData=[[self.selectionData objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sectionIndex]] mutableCopy];

        if (![sectionData containsObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:rowIndex]])
        {
            // cell is not selected before (new cell selection)
            //removing previous selected rows from the same section
            [sectionData removeAllObjects];
            [sectionData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:rowIndex]];

            [self.selectionData setObject:sectionData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sectionIndex]];
        }
        else
        {
            //cell you tapped is already selected,
            // you can deselect it by removing object

            //if you dont want to deselect it comment following lines
            //[sectionData removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:rowIndex]];

            [self.selectionData setObject:sectionData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sectionIndex]];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //section key not available so we need to create it
        NSMutableArray *sectionData=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [sectionData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:rowIndex]];

        [self.selectionData setObject:sectionData forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",sectionIndex]];

    }



    // todo: remove all rows in the next sections


    for (id key in self.selectionData) {
        // loop all next sections and deselect their rows
        if ([key intValue] > sectionIndex) {
            // this section comes after the current section
            // deselect
            [self.selectionData removeObjectForKey:key];

        }
    }
    NSLog(@"All Selection : %@",self.selectionData);
    NSLog(@"%@", self.selectionData);

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
//    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self handleSelectionForSection:indexPath.section row:indexPath.row];

...
}
```

## ERROR

```
2020-06-07 17:05:38.051339+1000 **********[69042:2401980] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSDictionaryM: 0x6000005ab3a0> was mutated while being enumerated.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab6f8db __exceptionPreprocess + 331
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109cd4ac5 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ab6c7ac __NSFastEnumerationMutationHandler + 124
    3   **********                 0x000000010445c267 -[SMGuidelinesSubProductsListViewController handleSelectionForSection:row:] + 1767
    4   ***********                 0x000000010445c4fa -[SMGuidelinesSubProductsListViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 170
    5   ************                 0x0000000104657352 -[SMTableDisposer tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] + 578
    6   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113f6ad4d -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1810
    7   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113f6af61 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 337
    8   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113d580e9 _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 318
    9   UIKitCore                           0x0000000113d475b9 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 358
    10  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113d74923 _afterCACommitHandler + 124
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aad62c7 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aad078e __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 430
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aad0e01 __CFRunLoopRun + 1505
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010aad04d2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 626
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010f08c2fe GSEventRunModal + 65
    16  UIKitCore                           0x0000000113d4cfc2 UIApplicationMain + 140
    17  ************                 0x00000001044cb230 main + 112
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010b5b8541 start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

**How can I prevent this error in the future?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try to understand the error message

> NSDictionaryM: 0x6000005ab3a0> was mutated while being enumerated

In the loop `for (id key in self.selectionData) {}` you are doing exactly what the error message says: You are removing items from the dictionary while being enumerated which is strongly discouraged.

A more reliable solution is to filter the keys with a predicate and remove all key/value pairs simultaneously

Replace

```
for (id key in self.selectionData) {
    // loop all next sections and deselect their rows
    if ([key intValue] > sectionIndex) {
        // this section comes after the current section
        // deselect
        [self.selectionData removeObjectForKey:key];

    }
}
```

with

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.intValue > %d", sectionIndex];
NSArray<NSString *> *filteredKeys = [self.selectionData.allKeys filteredArrayUsingPredicate: predicate];
[self.selectionData removeObjectsForKeys:filteredKeys];
```

Comment: for some reason, it's removing everything. it should remove the [key:value] where only key > sectionIndex

Comment: Actually it filters the keys as expected. I tested the code

Comment: Before the filter: self.selectionData = @"2" : 0 
After: self.selectionData : 0 key/value pairs
maybe because of the key is string?

Comment: Yes, indeed,  I was assuming that the keys are `NSNumber` objects. Please see the edit.